# bison shift/reduce conflict with the same token appear in the same rule

Tags: bison, reduce, shift

Given the following bison rules, I do not understand why the INTO token can be both shifted and reduced in the same bison state and caused 1 shift/reduce conflict. How to fix it ? The Capitals are all tokens.

```
select_condition: SELECT opt_select fields
                  FROM from_clause
                  opt_into_table
                  opt_into_graph
                  opt_where_expr

opt_into_table: { $$ = 0; }
              | INTO TABLE IDENTIFIER { $$ = 1; }

opt_into_graph: { $$ = 0; }
              | INTO GRAPH IDENTIFIER { $$ = 1; }

////// from the sqlparser.output //////////////////

INTO  shift, and go to state 66

INTO      [reduce using rule 31 (opt_into_table)]
$default  reduce using rule 31 (opt_into_table)

opt_into_table  go to state 67
```

Comment: I replaced the second INTO with 'into' and it works.  Is there any other better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict here is that when the parser sees the token `INTO` following a `from_clause`, there are two possibilities:

- it is the first token in the sequence `INTO TABLE IDENTIFIER`. In this case, it should be shifted (after reducing the `from_clause`).
- it is the first token in the sequence `INTO GRAPH IDENTIFIER`. In this case, an empty `opt_into_table` needs to be reduced before `INTO` is shifted.

So there is a shift/reduce conflict, because at that point it is not known whether or not an empty `opt_into_table` non-terminal needs to be reduced. With one more lookahead symbol, the answer would be clear so the grammar as written is LR(2). Unfortunately, bison doesn't produce LR(2) parsers.

As your semantic rules are written (with the semantic value of `IDENTIFIER` ignored in both cases), you could use a simple pragmatic fix: combine the two optional phrases into a single non-terminal, which creates a bit mask instead of two separate booleans:

```
opt_intos: INTO TABLE IDENTIFIER { $$ = 1; }
         | INTO GRAPH IDENTIFIER { $$ = 2; }
         | INTO TABLE IDENTIFIER INTO GRAPH IDENTIFIER { $$ = 3; }
```

But that may not be the best solution, since at some point you will probably care about the `IDENTIFIER`s.

Another (also somewhat ugly) possibility is to remove the epsilon productions, by creating expanding them into four different productions for `select_condition`:

```
select_condition: SELECT opt_select fields
                  FROM from_clause
                  into_table
                  into_graph
                  opt_where_expr
                | SELECT opt_select fields
                  FROM from_clause
                  into_graph
                  opt_where_expr
                | SELECT opt_select fields
                  FROM from_clause
                  into_table
                  opt_where_expr
                | SELECT opt_select fields
                  FROM from_clause
                  opt_where_expr

into_table      : INTO TABLE IDENTIFIER { $$ = 1; }

into_graph      : INTO GRAPH IDENTIFIER { $$ = 1; }
```

Another alternative is to combine `INTO TABLE` and `INTO GRAPH` into single tokens in the lexer. (For SQL-like languages, that is probably not going to work in general, because keywords are contextual. But in your case it might be feasible.)

Or you could just leave the grammar as it is, and use a `%glr-parser`.

Comment: @user3658306: upvote by clicking the upward pointing triangle beside the answer. Accept it by clicking the outline of a checkmark.